# Javascript custom Array.prototype interfering with for-in loops

Tags: javascript

I was attempting to extend Javascript's Object type with a function that retrieves all of the property names that are part of that object (basically what PHP's `array_keys()` function does to associative arrays).

```
Object.prototype.keys = function() {
    var a = [];
    for (var property in this) {
        a.push(property);
    }
    return a;
};

var a = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4};
alert(a.toSource());

var b = a.keys();
alert(b.toSource());
```

When the variable `b` was alerted, I was expecting to see `["a","b","c","d"]`, instead I'm seeing `["a","b","c","d","keys"]`.

It appears the for-in loop is including the prototyped `keys()` functions.

Is it possible to avoid this behaviour whilst still prototying, or should I just avoid prototyping all together?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ahh the joys of extending the built-ins. `for..in` checks up the entire prototype chain of the object being iterated.

What you need (and I believe this is de-facto now) is a check with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) in your loop:

```
for (var property in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        a.push(property);
    }
}
```

`hasOwnProperty` ensures that you only get properties that are directly defined on your object (i.e. *not* up the prototype chain).

Comment: Just for your information, `hasOwnProperty` is not supported in IE up to version 5.0 (5.5 has it) and Safari up to 2.02. You may decide that you're not bothered about supporting these browsers but you should know that you're not.

Answer (score 4):

For most situations, you should avoid extending the native `Object.prototype`. When you extend it, **ALL** objects receive those new properties.

Looping over an object properties is a really common task, and as you noted, you were experiencing an unexpected behavior.

I have not seen many people who *always* use the `hasOwnProperty` function in their code, I would say that under "controlled environments", maybe being a solo developer working on a project, you could manage those issues, but when the things get bigger, and you have more developers involved, this can cause a lot of problems.

What about making a *static* function on Object?

```
Object.keys = function(obj) {
  var a = [];
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      a.push(property);
    }
  }
  return a;
};

var a = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4};
alert(a.toSource());

var b = Object.keys(a);
alert(b.toSource());
```

Comment: **NOTE:** The `Object.keys` method has been introduced to the ECMAScript 5th Edition specification, and all recent browsers implement it, we have to check if the method is already defined before declaring it.

Answer (score 1):

> The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

So you can define non-enumerable properties.

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'foo', {
  value: 'bar',
  enumerable: false // Defaults to false.
});

const arr = [1,2,3];
for(const k in arr) console.log(k); // 0, 1, 2
console.log(arr.foo); // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
var items = [
    {
        id: 1, name: 'Item 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2, name: 'Item 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3, name: 'Item 3'
    }
];
items.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(item);
});
```