# Javascript "unique()" function

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I added `unique()` function to Javascript Array:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function(){
  return this.filter(function(item, ind, arr){
    return ind == arr.lastIndexOf(item);
  });
};
```

but when I iterate like this:

```
for (i in arr) { ... }
```

`i` becomes `unique` as well:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 1];
for (i in arr) {
    console.log(i + " ===> " + arr[i]);
}

// 0 ===> 1
// 1 ===> 2
// 2 ===> 1
// unique ===> function () { return this.filter(function (item, ind, arr) {return ind == arr.lastIndexOf(item);}); }
```

I know that I can iterate like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ... }
```

However, I still wonder if it's possible to add functions to `Array` and iterate like this:

```
for (i in arr) { ... }
```

?

Comment: you should not use for in when operating with an array http://stackoverflow.com/a/6974628/575527

Comment: Similar: [Javascript custom Array.prototype interfering with for-in loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529593/javascript-custom-array-prototype-interfering-with-for-in-loops), [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the `unique` property non-enumerable.

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "unique", { enumerable : false,
                                                  configurable : true});
```